# How do you get a document ID in the success callback when using jquery.couch.saveDoc?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

Example code is:

```
$db.saveDoc(doc, {
    success: function () {
        // Do something with the ID.
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Cannot save the thread.");
    }
});
```

In the success callback function, how do you get the ID of the doc that's just been saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much all jquery.couch functions call the success callback with the data returned from the http request, when you sent a POST /db/doc request,

```
{"ok":true,"id":"ad5c9fc93ae3b6f5f9809357a30003fe","rev":"1-2a91bdd9ee1e3e5e6302741132d7c415"}
```

is returned, so

```
$db.saveDoc(doc, {
  success: function (data) {
    var id = data.id;
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Cannot save the thread.");
  }
});
```